# What is the purpose of a field named "_" (underscore) containing an empty struct?

Tags: go, struct

I've seen two pieces of Go code using this pattern:

```
type SomeType struct{
  Field1 string
  Field2 bool
  _      struct{}    // <-- what is this?
}
```

Can anyone explain what this code accomplishes?

Comment: Unkeyed literals means this: `SomeType{"foo", true}` as opposed to `SomeType{Field1:"foo", Field2: true}` the `_ struct{}` field prevents the former.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/Golang-Nuts/NSjVW82i0mY/qSshj0qIYxQJ There is an exactly same question, but on golang-nuts.

Comment: Just try to create an unkeyed literal and you'll see.

Comment: I got the link by searching the code "ProgInfo". Hope this trick help you.

Comment: ... also please note that the prevention works only for client packages since the `_` is unexported, while inside the package that defines the type you can still do `SomeType{"foo", true, struct{}{}}`

Comment: That `_  struct{}` is a hack. I would highly suggest to always create a dedicated constructor via `NewX()` method. Better refactoring (u only change one method, not 100 places). Better control over default values when expanding attributes. Compiler will tell you exactly when and what is wrong if you miss an argument. Really don't understand why Go made constructors optional and leaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This technique enforces keyed fields when declaring a struct.

For example, the struct:

```
type SomeType struct {
  Field1 string
  Field2 bool
  _      struct{}
}
```

can only be declared with keyed fields:

```
// ALLOWED:
bar := SomeType{Field1: "hello", Field2: true}

// COMPILE ERROR:
foo := SomeType{"hello", true}
```

One reason for doing this is to allow additional fields to be added to the struct in the future without breaking existing code.

Comment: would you mind to explain what is "keyed" field now, and why do we need it?

Comment: @Nulik When you declare a struct with keyed fields, it looks like this: `SomeType{Field1: "hello", Field2: "true"}`. The `Field1` and `Field2` are the keys. Unless you use the technique described in this Q&A, Go will let you omit the keys when declaring the struct: `SomeType{"hello", true}`.

Comment: Is there a reference in the official Go documentation for this?

Comment: Note: unkeyed literals can still be used in this case e.g. `SomeType{"hello", true, struct{}{}}` [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qJLlV4xUiVg)