# Golang _ struct {} inside a struct. Whats the purpose of it?

Tags: go

In below definition of a structure, Whats the use of `_ struct{}` field? Why its there?

```golang
type DeleteItemOutput struct {
    _                     struct{}                   `type:"structure"`
    Attributes            map[string]*AttributeValue `type:"map"`
    ConsumedCapacity      *ConsumedCapacity          `type:"structure"`
    ItemCollectionMetrics *ItemCollectionMetrics     `type:"structure"`
}
```

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48381241/3068258.